# LWJGL 3: window doesn't show up

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I downloaded LWJGL 3 today, and found out that it was almost completly rewritten. I looked up a tutorial on how to create a window, but I still have problems creating a window.

The code runs without problems: no errors in the console, but the window isn't displayed!

I hope you can help me, I searched a lot for LWJGL 3 tutorials, but they seem pretty old, so I decided to ask my question here.

Here's my code:

//EDIT: Changed my code so everything runs in one thread but it still doesn' t work. Even System.out.println() doesn't work. No console output is displayed!

//IMPORTANT: I just realized that this may be a bug in GLFW (I'm working on Linux) !

```js
package net.newworld.test;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import org.lwjgl.Version;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWVidMode;

public class Main {
 
 private static long window;
 private static int width = 1280;
 private static int height = 800;
 
 private static void init() {
  
  glfwInit();
  
  System.out.println("Initializing LWJGL...");
  System.out.println("LWJGL Version: "+ Version.getVersion());
  
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GL_FALSE); //Set window visible after creation
  
  window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "New World", 0, 0);
  
  GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor()); //Get primary monitor
  
  glfwSetWindowPos(window, (vidmode.width() - width) / 2, (vidmode.height() - height) / 2); //Set window position
  
  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); //Make OpenGL contect current
  
  glfwShowWindow(window); //Show window
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  init();
 }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling the function `run()`?

Comment: @Poriferous because I implemented Runnable

Comment: That's probably the problem. You shouldn't have OpenGL/GLFW run another thread. Keep everything in one thread. Try and get rid of the `Runnable` interface, rewrite your code and see if that helps with your problem.

Comment: I changed my code (see above) but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You forgot to call the `glfwInit()` function.

Comment: Added it, still does nothing, may be a bug of GLFW (I'm working on Linux)...

Comment: http://goharsha.com/lwjgl-tutorial-series/hello-window/ Follow this tutorial. I have used GLFW but only in C++; Java shouldn't be too dissimilar as to its API but there's plenty missing that needs addressing. I use Linux too but I don't know if there's anything outstanding regarding GLFW.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that you forgot to add the window proc loop (which is blocking)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    init();
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwWaitEvents();
    }
}
```